# Should the hamburger menu close only on icon click or on click outside as well?

Tags: mobile, responsive, close, hamburger

We are using a hamburger menu on the mobile view of our responsive website, http://edmdesigner.com

There's a debate going on in the team:

a) Should the hamburger menu close if you click/tap outside of the open hamburger?

b) Or should it only close if you click/tap on the actual "hamburger icon"?

Comment: My two cents: I see hamburger menus as basically a type of modal. If I click outside the modal I generally expect that modal to close.

Comment: I don't see a hamburger menu on that website at all. Which is probably a good thing :) If you decide to have one, please allow the user to close it by touching any visible area outside of the expanded menu.

Comment: If you want to force your users to click the icon to close the menu, please dim the rest of the page to indicate that it is not clickable. I dislike popups that force me to find the X or "No Thank You" link.

Comment: I'm on mobile Safari, I can't see the menu OP is referring to. Could anyone point out where the menu is he's talking about?

Comment: As far as I'm aware when you click outside **any menu at all** the menu should disappear -- makes no difference if it is a "hamburger" based menu particularly. Actually, is there any case where you leave a menu open, when one clicks elsewhere??

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Some facts:

The image below is from the article [How Do Users Really Hold Mobile Devices?](http://www.uxmatters.com/mt/archives/2013/02/how-do-users-really-hold-mobile-devices.php). You can find plenty of other articles on the web about how users use a mobile phone. The data was collected by observing thousands of mobile phone owners remotely.

**Dark Orange / Red**  - *percentage of people who use their phone using thumb alone*

**Violet** - *Percentage of people who use their phone in cradle position*

**Magenta** - *two hands*

Others were engaged in a call or other activities ([see the article for details](http://www.uxmatters.com/mt/archives/2013/02/how-do-users-really-hold-mobile-devices.php)).

[image: Pie chart showing that orange is the largest group, violet is not far behind (between them making up half of the total), and magenta is a small proportion of the whole.]

**The above results show that 60-70% people use a single thumb to use the phone**. Mobile phone devices are getting larger and larger these days. The reachability of a single thumb is mostly on the lower part and towards the right.

The following image shows the areas where that thumb can reach:
[image: One Handed Thumb Reach]

In case of a hamburger menu, it would be an extra effort for the user to move his/her fingers to the position just to close it.

So it would be better if they can close it by tapping anywhere outside it.

Another point is the **user expectation**. Most users are familiar with the hamburger menu these days, and they will expect it to close if they tap outside the menu (just like a pop up box).

**Edit**

Adding the suggestions from the comments-

A swipe to close/open option is also highly recommended.

Users are used to swiping it in and out , this can be done independent of the screen positions - so highly recommended.

Comment: Also consider 'swipe to open' for the same reason.

Comment: and swipe to close menu, too.

Comment: The pie chart in itself is very confusing without more details.

Comment: I suppose you mean: "The reachability of a single thumb is mostly on the lower part and towards the _left_"?

Comment: No, the meaning was "There are two areas of reach: (1) The lower part. (2) The right (central) part." Though I had to read that twice, too.

Comment: The color names you've used seem off to me, which was very confusing. That is not red, but dark orange. And it's not pink (!!!), but something like dark magenta.

Comment: A percentage of people do refuse to buy larger phones for this very reason; I typically won't buy a phone if I can't reach the far top corner with my thumb while holding it in the "thumb-only" position.

Comment: Where's the pink in the pie chart? I see (going clockwise from the top) red,  dark blue, violet, blue, and yellow.

Comment: _In case of a hamburger menu , it would be an extra effort for the user to move his/her fingers to the position just to close it._ Um, isn't a finger there already when opening it?

Comment: @TaW user opens it to find some options , It's not mandatory that he/she keeps the finger in the same position all the time.

Comment: No, but hitting the same spot twice is always easier than hitting somewhere else. Also, after hitting an option the menu should close. That being said I see that in FireFox the HM will __only__ close when hitting the outside, not when hitting the HM twice; I don't like having to search for a spot outside, not to speak of the fear that when there is no __empty__ spot, hitting a button there might activate it.  It shouldn't but who knows. It should be visible that it won't but that is more complicated to recognize than simply hitting the menu again..

Answer (score 20):

### Let's evaluate the scenarios

**Users expect clicking on menu to close**

- If it closes on menu clicking => good
- Whether it closes touching
  outside or not=> don't care, because they'll use the button.
  Moreover  **most people won't be expecting a toggeable
  component to remain open when you click outside it** and even if
  someone expect this, **redoing the action won't be a pain or feel like
  a blocking situation**. Dropdowns, nav menus, modals,etc  closes when touching outside them most of the
  time.

**Users expect clicking outside to close**

- if it closes on menu clicking => Ok, it's expected
- if it closes touching outside => Great, as expected.
- if it **DOES NOT close** touching outside => **Users getting mad**

---

### Conclusion and advice

So if you want to reduce the probability of users getting mad, let them close the menu by tapping outside.

Also you should **prevent actions to execute (like links or buttons pressed) when the hamburger is open and the user tap outside it**. Although it's likely that this expectation is not the same for desktop.

Comment: Your last point, preventing actions from executing when tapping outside a menu or modal to close it, is incredibly important. A lot of sites don't do this, and on mobile many sites are so heavy with elements that can be interacted with that it makes tapping outside to close almost useless.

Comment: If only the stackexchange app reflected this, it would be a better app

Answer (score 16):

If you're going to use a hamburger menu, then it should collapse when you click or tap elsewhere (on desktop too, if the menu sticks instead of responds to unhover). Also on mobile other elements should not be activated when tapping off the menu.

But I think the correct answer, providing the best UX—which is your real goal, isn't it?—is: [don't use a hamburger menu at all](http://deep.design/the-hamburger-menu/).

> From [deep.design](http://deep.design/the-hamburger-menu/):
>
> **The Hamburger Menu Doesn't Work**
>
> It's a beautiful, elegant solution that gets it all wrong, and it's time to move on

The hamburger icon has no [information scent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_foraging#Information_scent). That's a big deal.

Comment: True. And because of that, it tends to turn into a junk drawer.

Comment: Indeed. And a good article link.

Comment: That's not really an answer to the question, now is it? I agree with you, hamburger menus are not ideal and should be avoided if possible, but that doesn't help OP in this case. He clearly states that the menu is already in place, but there is some discussion within his team about how to handle closing it.

Comment: Thanks for this post. I was looking for this article.


The "hamburger" is maybe not the best option, but quite easy to implement and many of the solution they use in the article to replace it, are not good enough either for our specific case. 


I would like to make all menu elements visible. We cannot add "icons" they won't make any sense. If we show menu elements in one row - they will be too small. Two rows take too much space... so "hamburger" seems to be a fast and easy solution, which is known by many (but obviously maybe not the best).

Comment: I was initially going to downvote you, but after reading the article I'm convinced.  Thanks!

Comment: @Kevin I think that there is a place for answers that don't just slavishly provide exactly what is asked. Answering "you shouldn't do that" may not help in the OP's specific case, but is likely to help someone else! I think your objection is short-sighted and thinking that way would make for a lower-quality site.

Comment: @DevilsAdvocate That's ironic, given your name (that you were going to downvote for my playing devil's advocate).

Comment: @ErikE What you did is not what "devil's advocate" means. Or are you saying you don't actually agree with your own answer?

Comment: @ErikE I don't really care if you think I'm short-sighted. The FAQ clearly states that an answer should answer the question ("Read the question carefully. What, specifically, is the question asking for? Make sure your answer provides that – or a viable alternative. The answer can be “don’t do that”, but it should also include “try this instead”."), which this one doesn't. It would've been different if OP was thinking about using a hamburger menu, but it's already done. Suggesting to just start over is not really helpful.

Comment: @Kevin How do you know the questioner is not suffering from the AB problem? How do you know that my answer hasn't helped him somehow? I answer on stackoverflow all the time with "that's not a good idea; don't do that" and it adds value to the site. There's no point in saying what several other answers have said already (yes, clicking off the menu should collapse it, and on mobile other links shouldn't work when doing so), but there is a *huge* point in somebody, anybody (who may as well be me) saying that hamburger menus are not good for UX. And isn't that what this is supposed to be about?

Comment: @Kevin I've updated my post event though it is really no different at all (in the context of the other, prior answers). Has that satisfied your rule-breaking annoyance? If not, please flag this post for moderator attention to be deleted (keeping in mind that at least 7 people have voted up my post so it's providing value to folks!).

Comment: @PixelSnader it was just humor—thought people'd laugh. Wikipedia says "... a position they do not necessarily agree with (or simply an alternative position from the accepted norm) ... . In taking this position, the individual taking on and playing the devil's advocate role seeks to engage others in an argumentative discussion process. The purpose of such a process is typically to test the quality of the original argument and identify weaknesses in its structure, and to use such information to either improve or abandon the original, opposing position." Seems legit as alternative from the norm?

Comment: That wasn't me that responded, but thanks for the explanation :)

Comment: @Kevin P.S. The OP even said "thanks for this post"! If he doesn't object ...

Answer (score 8):

The hamburger "menu" belongs to the menu class of UI patterns. therefor if you look how menus behave, they close in both instances when the user clicks/touches it again or somewhere outside its hit area.

The same would apply to hamburger menus as well.

Answer (score 5):

As the developer of [Picnic CSS](http://picnicss.com/), I have been wondering the same for a long time. I decided on closing it when clicked outside, but in any case, the **action should be made obvious**.

To make it obvious, when the menu is opened, **the rest of the content is obscured**:

[image: Picnic's image]

A notable example of how not to do it is github. Visit it on your mobile, click on the menu and try to close it (you have to click the same menu item, and links outside still work).

Comment: I've been trying to make a sidebar menu that doesn't push the existing content but rather appears on top of the main content! The project website that you've linked does this really well and even disables the buttons of the main content. Really cool! Will I get this behavior (easily) by using picnic.css?

Comment: Thanks! However, Picnic CSS is a full library, so only including the nav might be tricky. But yes, it's there by default, just open the page and resize the browser to see it. You could also just [copy the code for the nav](https://github.com/picnicss/picnic/blob/master/plugins/nav/_plugin.scss) and use it.

Answer (score 3):

Seems we're all in agreement here. I'll add another perspective on it.

[Fitts' Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fitts%27s_law) indicates that a larger tap target is easier to hit than a smaller one. So if you can make the entire background a target for closing the menu, then go for it.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your current layout and menu, I would also forego the hamburger menu.

You have a pretty limited amount of options, with low letter count. I would make the menu collapse from 1 line in to 2:

```
EDMdesigner | API | APP | ECMS | JOBS | BLOG | Login
```

---

```
EDMdesigner           Login     
API | APP | ECMS | JOBS | BLOG
```

---

But if you want to use a burger afterall, definitely go for 'close when pressed outside'. When people press outside of the menu, this can mean one of three things:

- they know (from similar cases) that it closes the menu.
- they want to use a different element on your side, so the menu is no longer needed.
- they accidentally mispress.

We're at the point where we can assume that the majority of users is 'literate' enough to know that to know that pressing outside of a menu will close it (see windows start menu etc) and those who don't yet know that won't randomly press outside of the menu, instead they will perhaps press the menu button again (if it opens when I click here, it must also close that way, right?) .

So we've got a majority group plus a minority that will press outside and get the expected effect, versus a (hopefully small, assuming your touch targets are large enough) minority that made a mistake. Would you sacrifice usability for the majority for the benefit of a minority of errors?

Answer (score -2):

The worthwhile answer here is:

## What the heck is a 'menu'?  It's not 1950!

Recall when software used to have insane numbers of "prefences" and stuff the user could "choose" - choose what font to display your text in! choose what font to display this menu in!  choose opening sounds! choose the background color! and so on.

That is all ancient history, a mistake everyone learned from.

Ever since Google realised the correct design of a web page...

(ie: "NO design. In fact, NO NOTHING"...)

everyone's finally realized that, in a word, apps should be as simple as possible.

Try and convince me why you "really need" the items in the menu in question, and in each case I'll just say "You don't need that, users don't give a crap, users will never use it, only minimalist apps make money."

So for me the answer is "it should never be necessary to close that menu, since it should not exist".   :O